# Windows 10 Anniversary update RDP Session Timeout

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-10, timeout

I recently updated my windows 10 installation with windows updates, upto the anniversary edition, and then a few more. Now every time I log into an RDP session, and then disconnect, and then I log in again after a longer period, it's a new session. If I disconnect and log in immediately after, it's still there, which makes me think the session stays open for a while and then times out. I tried all the options from this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272(v=ws.11).aspx and https://superuser.com/questions/969945/windows-10-remote-desktop-session-logs-off/991571 but none of it works. Please help!.

Comment: For the record, setting up RDP Session Host Configuration helped me alot at my time. But in your case those settings aren't applied, correct?

Comment: I enabled them, but I can't tell if they are being applied or not.

Comment: I wonder if the domain group policy is overriding them. Is there a way to tell?